# PowerShell ISE - Is there a keyboard shortcut for commenting out lines or multiple lines

Tags: powershell-ise

In PowerShell ISE I would like to comment out a line or multiple lines at once with a keyboard shortcut like how Sublime Text does this.

Is this possible to add or remove the `#` shown in the example below via a keyboard shortcut?

`[console]::beep(350,400)` < toggle betweeen these > `#[console]::beep(350,400)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution I like at https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/toggling-comments-in-powershell-ise.

It works for one or many lines, or even within lines. Place this function in your $Profile file.

```
function Toggle-Comment
{
    $file = $psise.CurrentFile                              
    $text = $file.Editor.SelectedText   
    if ($text.StartsWith("<#")) {
        $comment = $text.Substring(2).TrimEnd("#>") 
    }
    else
    {                            
        $comment = "<#" + $text + "#>"    
    }
    $file.Editor.InsertText($comment)                     
}

$psise.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add('Toggle Comment', { Toggle-Comment }, 'CTRL+K')
```

$Profile is run every time ISE is opened, so the function is always available. The function creates a new menu item with keyboard shortcut Ctrl-K that comments or uncomments the selected lines.

If the $Profile file is not yet created (it's often not), you can create it like this:

```
New-Item -Path $profile -ItemType "file" -Force
```

(source for command: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Thanks for that. You can see the path of the profile with this command in PS. `$profile`. When you can the path create a file called `Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1` in that path and use your code. Thanks again. Great first answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you added that.

Answer (score 6):

Not elegant but functional...

**To Comment**

"Block Select" at the start of all the lines by:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Mouse-Left-Click-Drag</kbd>
  or
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> while <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>

... then ...

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

**To UnComment**

"Block Select" all the **`#`** characters at start of all the lines by:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Mouse-Left-Click-Drag</kbd>
  or
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> while <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

... then ...

- <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: Please explain how this is any different from `put the cursor where you want the "#" and then type "#"`, and i am including the multi-select in my question.

Comment: Because you only have to type the "#" character once, vs typing it for every line.

Comment: if you can multi-select then you only have to type it once, too.

Comment: In that narrow regard, I suppose it's not any different.  I was addressing more of the 'spirit' of the question...  i.e...  how do you quickly comment/uncomment some code.  And while @Timo's answer may or may not link successfully to what I have, it's not really the SO "way"...  so I included the answer directly within my post.

Comment: I love this solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Old, but I just found this question and found this solution.

- Select all the lines you want to comment
- Ctrl-H to Replace in Script
- Type ^ in 'Find what'
- Type # in 'Replace with'
- Check the Regular Expression check box
- Replace All

Then in reverse use # in 'Find what' and nothing in 'Replace with'

Comment: A Keyboard shortcut is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to do that:

[Here](https://ridicurious.com/2015/04/07/powershell-quick-trick-to-multi-line-commenting-and-un-commenting-in-ise/) for multiple lines

[Here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-ISE-CommentUncom-c4bbe0f2) for single and multiple lines (my choice)

And a [detailed one](https://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-ise-multiline-comment-and-uncomment-done-right-and-other-ise-gui-must-haves/#:%7E:text=As%20you%20can%20see%20by,is%20Ctrl%2BShift%2BK.)

Answer (score -1):

## New solution using [ISESteroids](https://powershell.one/isesteroids/quickstart/install)

This is a much better solution but it involves installing a plugin for the ISE.

1. Paste this in the editor:
   `Install-Module -Name "ISESteroids" -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force`
2. Paste this to run it.
   `Start-Steroids`
3. Then select the text and use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Now you have this functionality inside the editor.

### To auto load [ISESteroids](https://powershell.one/isesteroids/quickstart/install)

1. To have [ISESteroids](https://powershell.one/isesteroids/quickstart/install) load every time you start PowerShell ISE, click on the icon shown

[image]

2. Paste this: `Start-Steroids`
3. Save this file and closse.
4. Next time you open PowerShell ISE, this plugin will load.

---

## Older defunct answer

This AFAIK cannot be done in the native editor but it can with:

https://code.visualstudio.com/

And by installing an extension called **PowerShell** by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and searching for `PowerShell` and installing.

This will allow debugging and syntax highlighting and also has the keyboard shortcuts for blocking out comments Like so:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for toggling a line comment
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for to toggling block comments.

Comment: This is not the answer I was Looking for.

Comment: I've since found a plugin for PowerShell ISE that will add this functionality so I have updated the answer.

Comment: broken site URLs

Comment: @IanSmith fixed. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks for fixing them!